# Делегирование класса

Tags: ооп, kotlin, конструктор, делегаты, best-practice

Я хочу иметь класс-обёртку, которая **делегирует** все свои *public* члены указанному объекту из этого класса. Для этого я использую ключевое слово *by*. Но этот код имеет несколько минусов:

1. объект **data** приходится делать изменяемым, хотя он устанавливается всего один раз при инициализации.
2. **data** не должен устанавливаться пользователем, но при этом его обязательно надо указать в первичном конструкторе.

```
class Cache(
    private val file: File,
    private var data: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
) : MutableMap<String, String> by data {

    init {
        data = Json.decodeFromStream(file.inputStream())
    }

    fun save() {
        Json.encodeToStream(data, file.outputStream())
    }
}
```

Какой самый логичный выход из этой ситуации?
Требуется, чтобы класс *Cache* обязательно реализовывал интерфейс *MutableMap<String, String>*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если параметр `data` в конструкторе не нужен, то его можно оттуда убрать. При этом добавить начальные данные из файла можно будет с помощью метода `putAll()`:

```kotlin
class Cache(
    private val file: File
) : MutableMap<String, String> by mutableMapOf() {

    init {
        putAll(Json.decode(file))
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо! Хочу оставить также своё решение:

```
class Cache(
    private val file: File
) : MutableMap<String, String> by loadFromJsonFile(file) {

    private companion object {
        fun loadFromJsonFile(file: File): MutableMap<String, String> {
            return Json.decodeFromStream(file.inputStream())
        }
    }

    fun save() {
        Json.encodeToStream(this, file.outputStream())
    }
}
```

Здесь используется `private companion object` для инкапсуляции и начальной инициализации данных. Решение может быть полезно тем, кому необходима неизменяемая **Map**.